# Passing a custom model to a Partial in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, model, razor-pages, partial-views

I have a partial page which is passed a list of Events (where an event is a custom Model). This works fine:

```
@model IEnumerable<Entry>
@using MySite.Models
```

Within the partial page I iterate through the list of Entry's in the model:

```
    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var entry in Model)
        {
          ...
```

This works fine as well. However, within this `foreach` loop I want to send the data of the entry to another partial view:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Pages/Shared/ShareMedia/shareMedia.cshtml", @entry)
```

Within this partial I have declared the following:

```
@model Entry
```

However this seems t return an error:

```
error CS0118: 'Entry' is a namespace but is used like a type
```

If I then try to add the full path of the model

```
@model MySite.Models.Entry
```

I get the following error when trying to load the partial:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MySite is not defined
at HTMLImageElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

Is there any advice anyone might be able to give to help me get around this. I have done some googlinig but not getting any direction.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are mixing up MySight and MySite

Comment: That is a good spot. MySite/MySight is just a placeholder I typed in to this Stack Overflow  question in place of the real placeholder. The real placeholders in my code actually match. Appreciate the response though! I have corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better don't name a class as the same with a namespace.Try to change the `Entry` name,for example,`EntryModel`.And then use

```
@model IEnumerable<EntryModel>
```

partial view:

```
@model EntryModel
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MySite is not defined at
> HTMLImageElement.onclick ((index):1)
> The error is usually happended when a function in onclick event is not defined.For example:

```
<button onclick="MySite()">click</button>
```

and if `MySite()` is not defined in js,it will get the error.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is the thing.... I don't have Entry as a Namespace anywhere that I can see, it is just a Model. It is only when I fully qualify the model Entry it recognises it as such. Only then I get the Uncaught ReferenceError mentioned above.

Comment: Actually, I think the issue is that I need to seralize my model for it to get sent into the Javascript function (which I didnt actually include in the above example!) lol

Comment: Can you share your js?